# Recommendation request for a book explaining string theory to a common idiot (me)

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I find the idea of string theory fascinating, but I'm not a student of physics, mathematics or science in general. Are there any books which effectively break down the concepts in a way that laymen like me can understand without being overly simple but also overly technical?

Comment: [This](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38399) is related, possibly a duplicate.

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29007/2451

Comment: For the layman I do recommend "The elegant universe" by Brian Greene. See the discussion in the related posts.